# Scanning for annotated classes does not work with Instant Run

Tags: java, android, annotations

With [Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview5available) and the android gradle plugin *2.0.0-alpha5* it is not possible to scan for annotated classes anymore.
That is because with *Instant Run* the *apk* is sliced into several parts.

Loading the dex file with

```
DexFile dex = new DexFile(context.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir);
```

leads to the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/<...>.Android-1/base.apk
```

I don't want to disable *Instant Run*. Are there any other ways do load the *DexFile* or the splitted *DexFiles*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, it does not work anymore.

The long answer is: Use a custom `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` and generate code. You can integrate the processor with [android-apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt) into your gradle build process.

I have a simple example [here](https://github.com/mohlendo/android-apt-example) that shows how to collect classes with annotation and how to generate a static registry.